# Accepting multiple elements from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to input multiple elements from the lists and have the program print the accurate "pointCount" amount. It works if I type in one element from either list (e.g. "a" = 1 point, "f" = 3 points). The problem is that if I, for example, input something like "cafe", the program will just print out "0 points" instead of "7 points".

```
onePointLetters = ["a", "b", "c"]
twoPointLetters = ["d", "e"]
threePointLetter = ["f"]
enterLetter = input("Enter a letter: ").lower()
while enterLetter != "stop":
    pointCount = 0
    if enterLetter in onePointLetters:
        pointCount += 1
    if enterLetter in twoPointLetters:
        pointCount += 2
    if enterLetter in threePointLetter:
        pointCount += 3
    print("You have a total of " + str(pointCount) + " points!")
    enterLetter = input("Enter another letter: ").lower()
```

I tried another coding alternative.

```
onePointLetters = ["a", "b", "c"]
twoPointLetters = ["d", "e"]
threePointLetter = ["f"]
enterLetter = input("Enter a letter: ").lower()
while enterLetter != "stop":
    pointCount = 0
    for onePointLetters in enterLetter:
        pointCount += 1
    for twoPointLetters in enterLetter:
        pointCount += 2
    for threePointLetter in enterLetter:
        pointCount += 3
    print("You have a total of " + str(pointCount) + " points!")
    enterLetter = input("Enter another letter: ").lower()
```

The latter seemed to work as intended if I keep one of the "for" loops. But if I keep all three, the program would just add all the value and end up with 6 points for each letter entered (d = 6 points, afe = 18 points).

Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: that's because you must treat input string as set of separate letters for your score logic to work. Just iterate (i.e. `for`) over `enterLetter`. There will be more changes needed but you will figure that out

Comment: Although your question is specific to a needed fix, I think the use of `dict` would make your code more cleaner and easier to understand. A key/value of letter-point is my suggestion and yes, you need to loop over the input

Comment: Maybe its bad on my part, but I'd just do list comprehension, then sum it, like so: `sum([1 if e in onePointLetter else (2 if e in twoPointLetter else (3 if e in threePointLetter else 0)) for e in list(enterLetter)])`. The thing is as astrochun mentioned, you should be using a dictionary here, so the way you've implemented it, anything can go (such as my bad idea for list comprehension here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first coding attempt checks whether the input is in the pointlists. "a" is in the list, therefore one point. "f" is also in the list, therefore 3 points. "Cafe" however, is in none of the lists.

You need to find a way to loop through each letter of the input-word, and check what amount of points they should add to pointsCounter.

```
onePointLetters = ["a", "b", "c"]
twoPointLetters = ["d", "e"] 
threePointLetters = ["f"]
enterWord = input("Enter a letter: ").lower()

while enterWord != "stop":
    pointCount = 0

    # Loop through every letter of the word entered
    for letter in enterWord:
        # Adds points to pointCount according to the pointsystem
        if letter in onePointLetters:
            pointCount += 1
        elif letter in twoPointLetters:
            pointCount += 2
        elif letter in threePointLetters:
            pointCount += 3
    print("You have a total of " + str(pointCount) + " 
    points!")
    enterWord = input("Enter another letter: ").lower()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll keep a note of your solution. And like the others stated, I'll make sure to use the dictionary for future preference.

Answer (score 1):

Your first code works but you should initialize pointCount outside of the while loop

I would suggest using a dictionary for this:

```
letterPoints = {"a":1, "b":1, "c":1, "d":2, "e":2, "f":3}
pointCount   = 0
while True:
    enterLetter  = input("Enter a letter: ").lower()
    if enterLetter == "stop": break
    pointCount  += letterPoints.get(enterLetter,0)
    print("You have a total of", pointCount, "points!")
```

Comment: Glad to see someone suggesting `dict`.